# If $\mu$ is a measure on (X, $\mathcal{M}$), can $\mu$ be semifinite on a finite space X?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking at Folland 1.3 #15 and I don't see what I'm misunderstanding in this question. The question is to show $\mu_0(E) = \sup\{ \mu(F) : F\subset E, \mu(F) < \infty \}$ is semifinite. If $\mu$ is described as in the question, if I take $X=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathcal{M}=2^X$, and $\mu(\{1\}) = \infty$,$\mu(\{0\}) = 0$, then how can $\mu_0$ be semifinite?

Comment: To ease our possibilities to help you, please post a full description of the exercise.

Comment: My bad. I was in a rush. @Furrer

Answer (score 1):

In your example $\mu_0$ is the zero measure, which is certainly semifinite.

Comment: Doesn't a semifinite measure require a subset $F \subset E$ s.t. $\mu(F) > 0$? If we take $E = {1}$, then the only proper subset of $E$ is the empty set. Something seems wrong here...with my understanding

Comment: @Ken: Folland's definition of "semifinite" is "for each $E \in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(E) = \infty$ there exists $F \in \mathcal{M}$ with $F \subset E$ and $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$".  For $\mu_0$, there are no sets $E$ with $\mu_0(E) = \infty$ so the definition is vacuously satisfied; we are not required to find any sets $F$.